# Ways to open info window when the mouse is over a marker

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have done this much

```
function xmlParser(xml) {
    $('#load').fadeOut();
    var marker=[];
    $(xml).find("da").each(function () {
        $(".main").prepend('<div class="data"><div class="name">Name ' + $(this).find("name").text() + '</div><div class="latitude">Latitude ' + $(this).find("lat").text() + '</div><div class="longitube">Longitude ' + $(this).find("lng").text() + '</div></div>');
        $(".data").fadeIn(1000);
        var lat = parseFloat($(this).find('lat').text());     
        var lng = parseFloat($(this).find('lng').text()); 
        var idd = parseInt($(this).find('id').text());
        //var lat=parseFloat(latt);
        var content=idd+$(this).find("name").text()+'<br/>'+$(this).find("lat").text() + '<br/>'+ $(this).find("lng").text() ;
        //var lng=parseFloat(lngg);
        marker.push({latitude: lat,
              longitude: lng, id :'testMarker',
              html: { content: content, }
        })
    });

    $("#map").goMap({ 
        markers: marker
    }); 
    $.goMap.createListener({type:'marker', marker:'testMarker'}, 'mouseover', function() { }); 
}
```

So basically values are coming from the database using ajax. Also when I click on one of the markers I get the information I require. Every marker's window has different information. So now I want the info window to open using mouseover event on the markers.
The above mouse over event function is working properly but I don't know how to open the info window using this event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
 $.goMap.createListener({type:'marker', marker:'testMarker'}, 'mouseover', function() { 
     google.maps.event.trigger($($.goMap.mapId).data('testMarker'), 'click');
 });
```

It just triggers Google's own event to click on the marker 'testMarker'.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but i want mouseover event...and i have multiple markers having different data.

Comment: It is mouseover. Only in the mouseover function your trigge a click which opens the infowindow. The way the `$.goMap` plugin works there is no place for `mouseover`.